# How to download a file from a web application without using respone properties?

Tags: excel, vb.net, http, asynchronous, download

I have a button on click it will download some data from the a path. I am trying to make this button call event a asynchronous one.

Under button click event i am calling the asynchronous method
Public Delegate Function delAsyncMethodCaller()

```
   **ButtonClick Method**
    Dim obj As New delAsyncMethodCaller(AddressOf downloadReport)
    Dim iAr As IAsyncResult = obj.BeginInvoke(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AsyncComplete), Nothing)

   Public Function downloadReport()

    ------Some Operation--------
        strFileName = "Test"
        Response.Clear()
        Response.ClearHeaders()
        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileName)
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12"
        Response.BinaryWrite(exHelper.DownloadDocument(strDestinationPath & strFileName))
        Response.End()

   End Function
```

As it is as asynchrounous call, the Response property is returned as null. How can i download the file without using the response properties.

Comment: Ehm, the `Response` code you have there is for _sending_ data to a client. It is used by websites to send the file that a client wants to download. To download a file via your application you shouldn't use a `Response`, you should use a [**`WebClient`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: i tried using webclient, its throwing file not found exception though i am able to access the shared path

Comment: I am trying to download data from shared path like this \\appsupld\Uploads\OfficeAutomation\OMA\Downloads\

Comment: Oh, well for a network share, rather than a URL, I think [**`File.Copy()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx) would be better. If you still get an exception please edit the question and show me the exact code you're using. Also check the resulting path so that it really points to the file you want to access.